# Looping with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a show and hide function for some divs and more divs need to be added:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=des_]').hide();

    $('.notification, .description span').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
    });

    $("#list_01").click(function() {
        $("#des_01").show();
        $("#des_02").hide();

    });

    $("#list_02").click(function() {
        $("#des_02 ").show();
        $('#des_01').hide();
    });

});
```

How do I hide all the other divs when one is opened? Can someone help?

Working example is http://jsfiddle.net/tpWEk/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the naming conventions for your `div` IDs are all going to follow the same pattern, you could do something like this, so you don't need to repeat code for every new element:

```
$("div[id^='list_']").click(function() {
    $("div[id^='des_']").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpWEk/35/). It uses the "[attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector to bind a click event handler to all `div` elements whose `id` starts with "list_". In that event handler it hides all `div` elements whose `id` starts with "des_", gets the next element (which in your example is the correct `div`) and shows that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".notification").click(function() {
        $(".description").hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your work and preventing reinventing the wheel, you may have a look at jQuery Accordion: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Demo working on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ANCbg/2/

Hope this is useful for your project!